# php fix parse error syntax error unexpected

Tags: php, laravel

to prevent the penetration of misinformation into the system (for example, the father is younger than the child, or the surname of the father and child are not the same) we are asked to design two classes called Person and Father in a way that can be Use:

```
$father = Father::firstName('Esaaro')->lastName('Ozaaraa')->age(42);

Person::firstName("Soobaasaa")->lastName( "Ozaaraa")->age(17)
  ->setFather( $father )-> toArray();
```

i have return this output but codes have some problem.

```
$person = [
    'firstName' => 'Soobaasaa',
    'lastName' => 'Ozaaraa',
    'age' => 17,
    'father' => [
        'firstName' => 'Esaaro',
        'lastName' => 'Ozaaraa',
        'age' => 42
    ]
];
```

the details
The conditions that are considered for the characteristics of father and child are:

First and last name must be of string type and at least 3 and at most 15 letters and must not contain numeric characters. For example: 'kaakero12' is not acceptable

The age of the child should be of the type int and from 1 to 130. (For example, the number 0 or 131 is not acceptable as the input value of the age method.)

The father must be at least 18 and at most 130 years old. (For example, the number 17 or 131 is not acceptable as the input value of the age method.)

The input value to the setFather method must be an object of class Father.

The age of the father and child must be at least 18 years old.

Note that the age of both father and child must be certain (a child who is not old cannot have a father and vice versa)

Last name LastName Father and child must be the same.

**my answer:**

**plese help to find problems.**

```
<?php
    
    class Person
    {
        private $firstName;
        private $lastName;
        private $age;
        private $father;
    
        private function __construct(string $firstName) {
            $this->firstName = $firstName;
        }
    
        public static function firstName(string $name = 'testhhhhhh') {
            return new Person($name);
        }
    
        public function lastName(string $lastName) {
            $this->lastName = $lastName;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function age(int $age) {
            $this->age = $age;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function setFather(Father $father) {
            $this->father = $father;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function toArray() {
            $this->father->age 
            ( (isset($this->firstName) && $this->firstName !== null  &&  strlen($this->firstName) >= 3  &&  strlen($this->firstName) <= 15  && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $this->firstName) == false) ? $this->Person=['firstName'] == $this->firstName : '' );
            ( (isset($this->lastName) && $this->lastName !== null  &&  strlen($this->lastName) >= 3  &&  strlen($this->lastName) <= 15  && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $this->lastName) == false) ? $this->Person=['lastName'] == $this->lastName : '' );
            ( (isset($this->age) && $this->age >= 1  &&  $this->age <=130   && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $this->age) == false) ? $this->Person=['age'] == $this->age : '' );
            $this->Person=['father'    => $this->father->toArray()];
        }
    }
    
    class Father
    {
        protected static $name;
        protected $family, $age, $result;
    
        public static function firstName(string $name = null)
        {
            self::$name = $name;
        }
    
        public function lastName(string $lastName = null)
        {
            $this->family = $lastName;
        }
    
        public function age(string $age = null)
        {
            $this->age = $age;
        }
    
        public function toArray()
        {
            ( (isset(static::$name) && static::$name !== null && strlen(static::$name) >= 3 && strlen(static::$name) <= 15) ? $this->result['firsName'] = self::$name : '' );
            ( (isset($this->family) && $this->family !== null  &&  strlen($this->family) >= 3  &&  strlen($this->family) <= 15  && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $this->family) == false) ? $this->result['lastName'] = $this->family : '' );
            ( (isset($this->age) && $this->age !== null && $this->age >= 18 && $this->age <=130 && $this->age > (Person::age() +  18) ? $this->result['age'] = $this->age : '' );
            return $this->result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: class Person toArray missing a return

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial how to fix  problem?

Comment: add a return? did you go through the code?

Comment: Your title mentions "_fix parse error syntax error unexpected_", what is the exact error you get, which line? And `$this->Person` ? Where is it defined?

Comment: no. This question is a recruitment test and I have difficulty providing the correct answer.

Comment: @brombeer father class, to array method line 3 return problem

Answer (score 0):

There are several design issues with your approach :

You don't need the Father class. It doesn't guarantee that the Person object will have a younger age than the Father object. Your Father class doesn't have any different property or rule in terms of data. You can use the Person class alone, and set your rule about the age in the `setFather` method (a better approach may be to do the validation outside the Model classes, but it's up to you depending on your current program architecture).

The naming of your methods are not clear either. `age()` sets the age of your Person instance, but `firstName()` is static and creates a new instance ?? Why would you call `$person = Person::firstname('Test');` instead of `$person = new Person('Test');` ? I think you don't need that static method, the constructor does the same job and is more legitimate to do it.

You should have proper getters and setters to make your class easier to understand. Like `setAge()` and `getAge()`.

Your `toArray()` methods are quite a mess too. What is this method supposed to do ? Its name would indicate that it would give an array of your Person properties, but in fact you're doing the validation here.

It's too late to validate an object which already has wrong values. When you're calling `toArray()`, you already have a Person object full of invalid data. The validation must be done before, when trying to set the property value. `toArray()` should only return values, without checking what they are.

I think with all that done, you should see with more comfort how to do what's asked of you :).

Comment: plese view this link:
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=fa&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fquera.ir%2Fproblemset%2Ftechnology%2F17309%2F%D8%B3%D8%A4%D8%A7%D9%84-php-%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2